# Access adding 21 days to a date

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to have a date in a field in a db called entry date, and a field called finish date, the entry date will be pre populated but i want the finish date to be 21 days later, is there a method to be able to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using Microsoft Access. The finish date  field (column) can be updated in the After Update event of a start date control on a form, or you can create a query that updates the field, or since Access 2010, you can use a [data macro](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2009/08/13/access-2010-data-macros-similar-to-triggers.aspx). However, if the date is always 21 days in advance of the start date, do you need a field (column) at all? A query will allow you to show the end date easily enough:

```
SELECT StartDate, StartDate + 21 As EndDate
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Sorry should have added its Access 2003 that i am using, looked at the option of running a query which i understand how to do and save the query as a table but i wanted to do it automatically i have looked at 2010 and i can see there is a calculation field in the table design which would do this but in 2003 it doesnt have this, I have tried to add this to the dateb field in table design under default value - DateAdd("d",21,'DateA') but it is giving me a data type mismatch but worked how i expected if i enter DateAdd("d",21,"01/12/2011"). Also need a seperate field as i cant override the data.

Comment: @user445714 You do not need dateadd, just add 21 days ( `=Me.StartDate + 21` ) and use the after update event of start date, not the control source. Do not use default value, your start date will not exist at the time it runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
In opposite of Excel that directly you can add to date There is Function to add day or month or year to Date in Access.
Exmaples:

DateAdd('d', 130 , Date)
DateAdd('d', 430 , FirstDate) //add month and year by calculating extra days
DateAdd('m',3 , Date)
DateAdd('y', 2 , Date)
```